# Dimension Reduction for High Dimensional Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, pca, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction

I have often seen dimension reduction techniques being performed on datasets, such as the famous Iris Flower dataset (below: common visualization techniques applied on a medical dataset):

[image]

**However, I have always wondered if these kinds of dimension reduction techniques (e.g. Principal Component Analysis (PCA), TSNE (T Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding) and UMAP (Uniform Manifold Approximation)) can be used (i.e. are meant to be used) to visualize high dimensional  probability distributions** . To illustrate my example, I created some some high dimensional data, applied these dimension reduction techniques (using the R programming language) as follows:

First, I created the data (5 Dimensional Data):

```
library(Rtsne)
library(umap)
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(bivariate)

var_1 = rnorm(1000,10,10)

var_2 = rnorm(1000,10,5)

var_3 = rnorm(1000,10,8)

var_4 = rnorm(1000,2,2)

var_5 = rnorm(1000, 6,1)

my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5)
```

Next, I applied the dimension reduction techniques:

**1) PCA (Principal Component Analysis)**

```
res.pca <- prcomp(my_data, scale = TRUE)

pca_out <- data.frame(res.pca$x[, c(1,2)])
```

**2) TSNE (T Stochastic Neighbor Embedding)**

```
tsne <- Rtsne(my_data, pca=TRUE, check_duplicates=FALSE, perplexity=20, theta=0.5, dims=2)
tsne_out = data.frame(tsne$Y[, c(1,2)])
```

**3) UMAP (Uniform Manifold Approximation)**

```
umap <- umap(my_data)
umap_out <- data.frame(umap$data[,c(1,2)])
```

Next, I performed different visualizations on these dimension reduction techniques:

**A) Fit Bivariate Normal Distributions (Assume No Covariances):**

```
#PCA

plot_pca <- bmbvpdf (
    mean.X1= mean(pca_out$PC1), mean.X2=mean(pca_out$PC2),
    
    sd.X1=sd(pca_out$PC1) ,   sd.X2=sd(pca_out$PC2),
)

plot(plot_pca)

#TSNE 

plot_tsne <- bmbvpdf (
    mean.X1= mean(tsne_out$X1), mean.X2=mean(tsne_out$X2),
    
    sd.X1=sd(tsne_out$X1) ,   sd.X2=sd(tsne_out$X2),
)

plot(plot_tsne)

#UMAP


plot_umap <- bmbvpdf (
    mean.X1= mean(umap_out$var_1), mean.X2=mean(umap_out$var_2),
    
    sd.X1=sd(umap_out$var_1) ,   sd.X2=sd(umap_out$var_2),
)

plot(plot_umap)
```

[image]

**B) Contour Plots**

```
 ggplot(pca_out, aes(x = pca_out$PC1, y = pca_out$PC2)) +
        geom_density_2d_filled() + ggtitle("PCA Plot")

 ggplot(tsne_out, aes(x = tsne_out$X1, y = tsne_out$X2)) +
        geom_density_2d_filled() + ggtitle("TSNE plot")

 ggplot(umap_out, aes(x = umap_out$var_1, y = umap_out$var_2)) +
        geom_density_2d_filled() + ggtitle("UMAP plot")
```

[image]

**C) Kernel Density Estimates**

```
#pca

kd <- with(pca_out, MASS::kde2d(pca_out$PC1, pca_out$PC2, n = 50))

 plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface() %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "PC1"), yaxis = list(title = "PC2"))) %>%     layout(title = "KDE of Principal Component Analysis")

#TSNE 
kd <- with(tsne_out, MASS::kde2d(tsne_out$X1, tsne_out$X1, n = 50))

 plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface() %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "TSNE1"), yaxis = list(title = "TSNE2"))) %>%     layout(title = "KDE of TSNE")

#UMAP

kd <- with(umap_out, MASS::kde2d(umap_out$var_1, umap_out$var_2, n = 50))

plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface() %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "UMAP1"), yaxis = list(title = "UMAP2"))) %>%     layout(title = "KDE of UMAP")
```

[image]

**D) Fit Gaussian Mixture Models to the Reduced Data**

```
library(Mclust)

#PCA

mod1 <- Mclust(pca_out, G = 3)
summary(mod1, parameters = TRUE)

#TSNE
mod2 <- Mclust(tsne_out, G = 3)
summary(mod2, parameters = TRUE)

#UMAP

mod3 <- Mclust(umap_out, G = 3)
summary(mod3, parameters = TRUE)
```

If you look at anyone of these outputs (mod1, mod2, mod3 - these are all in the same format, I will just show one of them for the sake of brevity) :

```
 summary(mod1, parameters = TRUE)
---------------------------------------------------- 
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
---------------------------------------------------- 

Mclust EII (spherical, equal volume) model with 3 components: 

 log-likelihood    n df       BIC       ICL
      -2892.281 1000  9 -5846.733 -6978.427

Clustering table:
  1   2   3 
694 187 119 

Mixing probabilities:
        1         2         3 
0.5167668 0.2738747 0.2093585 

Means:
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
PC1 -0.001083778 -0.4748532  0.6238598
PC2  0.319327849 -0.3277565 -0.3594495

Variances:
[,,1]
         PC1      PC2
PC1 0.929556 0.000000
PC2 0.000000 0.929556
[,,2]
         PC1      PC2
PC1 0.929556 0.000000
PC2 0.000000 0.929556
[,,3]
         PC1      PC2
PC1 0.929556 0.000000
PC2 0.000000 0.929556
```

This means that on the PCA Reduced Data, the following multivariate gaussian mixture model was fit to the data:

```
0.51 * Bivariate_Normal_Distribution_1 [mean = (-0.001, 0.319), cov = (0.929, 0.929)] + 0.27 * Bivariate_Normal_Distribution_2 [mean = (-0.47, 0.319), cov = (0.929, -0.327)] + Bivariate_Normal_Distribution_3 [mean = (0.62, 0.35), cov = (0.929, -0.327)]
```

The likelihood and BIC of this model fit is also recorded (which can be used to judge how well the model fits the data):  `-2892.281` and `-5846.733`

**My Question** Is all this work that I have done unnecessary and meaningless? In the real world, do researchers ever try to reduce the dimensionality of the data, and then try to fit probability distributions to the reduced data? Or is too much information lost during the dimensionality reduction which makes fitting probability distributions to reduced data meaningless? I would have thought that maybe fitting probability distributions to reduced data might reduce computational time - but even if computational time is reduced (i.e. algorithms like TSNE are known to take a long time to reduce the dimensionality of large datasets), if too much information is lost during the dimensionality reduction - is all this still irrelevant? Another disadvantage of fitting probability distributions to reduced data is the loss of interpretability when performing statistical inference on the probability distribution of this reduced data (e.g. how exactly does the original data "map" to the reduced data?) - and the fact that it might be complicated to "map" new data as well (e.g. it's not advised to do this with TSNE).

At the end of the day, is it simply better to some Bayesian/MCMC (Markov Chain Monte Carlo) algorithm to fit probability distributions to the original data instead of the reduced data?

Thanks!

Note: If all else fails, I hope the R code that I have used in this question can at least serve as a general tutorial for other people in the future who want to try similar techniques.

Comment: Your questions appears to be 'if data reduction fails is there any point to statistically analysing it?'. Simulated data differs from collected data in that your know in advance whether data reduction should or should not work. The initial variables appear to be generated without any correlation in their variation so data reduction would be expected to not produce any meaningful benefit. If you create the variables using a copula, or use mathematical functions to mix the variables into new correlated ones then you would expect data reduction to start showing some benefit.